# Should I nullify fields when destroying GameObjects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-management

If a field is set via Inspector, should I nullify it when destroying the GameObject or Unity does that automatically?

```
public class TestClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image Icon;
    public Button CloseButton;

    private void Start()
    {
        Icon.color = Color.black;
        CloseButton.onClick.AddListener( MyButtonListener );
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        CloseButton.onClick.RemoveListener( MyButtonListener );

        //DO I NEED THIS?
        Icon = null;
        CloseButton = null;
    }

    private void MyButtonListener() { }
}
```

Comment: Do either of those types (`Image` / `Button`) implement `IDisposable`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> If a field is set via Inspector, should I nullify it when destroying
>   the GameObject or Unity does that automatically?

No, you don't have to set Unity Object to `null` before or after destroying it. Unity's Object has an `==` operator overload. When Object is destroyed, Unity marks the object as `null` but the Object is not really `null`. This is a mechanism implemented so that you check if it is `null` with `if(unityObject == null)`. When it is marked as null, it makes no sense to set it to null again.

Note that when you said destroy, I assume that you are destroying the object with the [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) or [`DestroyImmediate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html) function. Also, if you're just unsubscribing from an event like you did in your question, you don't need to destroy the object. You also don't need to set it to `null`.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I'm destroying the object by calling the `Destroy` function. Wanted to be sure that all references are null so GC can properly deallocate the memory.

Comment: While Unity internally differentiates between a reference that's not been set and a reference to an object that got destroyed, as Programmer said it overlads the == operator so the result is identical from code point of view